# Inyección de dependencias en Spring con TestNG

Tags: java, spring, test-ng

Spring soporta JUnit muy bien de esta forma:
Con las anotaciones `RunWith` y `ContextConfiguration`, el código queda muy intuitivo

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:dao-context.xml")
```

Este test queda disponible para correr tanto con Eclipse y Maven de forma correcta.
Me pregunto si se puede realizar algo similar con TestNG. Estoy considerando migrar mis pruebas a este *framework*, pero no he encontrado la forma de extrapolar estas pruebas con Spring, de Junit a TestNG.

Comment: Que tal, yo seguí esta guía y no tuve mayor problema. http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-spring-integration-example/ Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta manera, finalmente funcionó:

```
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class TestValidation extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    public void testNullParamValidation() {
        // Testing code goes here!
    }
}
```